# Using WNS for Windows phone Silverlight 8.1-MPNS for Windows phone 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mpns, win-phone-silverlight-8.1, wns

I have developed Windows Phone 8 application and implemented MPNS(Microsoft Push Notification Services).

**I have upgraded the app from Windows Phone 8 version to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013, As per this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642085%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) I found WNS is recommended by Microsoft. As It has evolved with new features and advancements.

But when planned to go with WNS I need to have MOBILE SERVICE as a back-end. something like Microsoft Azure Mobile services, which is payable one.

Contacted Azure Mobile support for the same they say it's for UWP(Universal Windows Apps) if that's the only case, how to proceed with WNS in my upgraded application, or did he explain something wrong?

And also I have obtained Symantec mobile code signing certificate - 299$ can I use the same to signing MPNS and WNS?

Comment: When your cloud service(Azure Mobile Service in my case) has an update to send, it notifies WNS using the channel URI. This is done by issuing an HTTP POST request, including the notification payload, over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL). This step requires authentication. Exactly here can I use  the Symantec Certficate or need SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the WNS notifications in a Windows Phone app built using the MobileFirst tooling, you need to read the documentation. Like this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_win8.html?lang=en.

It doesn't matter that you're app is a Hybrid app.

Comment: Thanks you Idan Adar, as per the link you sent and as per Vivin K reply, I guess I actually need to convert my application to Windows Phone 8 Universal application before setting up push notification(WNS). I did my ground work and found this link: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/29/windows-universal-apps-part-1-native-apps/   will this be sufficient to convert the application to UWP? Also as per IBM MobileFirst version, We are not upgrading to 7.1.0 we are currently developing with 7.0.0 will that be a problem for any or should i upgrade to 7.1.0 to do this?

Comment: I have license for "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation V7.0 Consumer Edition" Do we need to pay for the license of "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation V7.1 Consumer Edition" ?

Comment: Call your IBM contact person to find the answer for that.

Comment: OK Idan If i go with 7.0.0 and upgrade my applicaton to UWP will it be fine?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. There is an MFPF SDK for UWP. Use it as you develop your application.

Comment: OK thank you Name,Publisher, Package Security Identifier (SID)
Client Secret. where to find Package Security Identifier (SID) in my Dashboard I don't see any to add to application-descriptor.xml

Answer (score 0):

In IBM MobileFirst Platform, WNS is applicable only for Universal Windows Apps (as already mentioned) .

To use WNS notifications:

a) if you are using a hybrid application, add a "Windows 8 Universal" environment. The resultant UWP project structure contains a WP8.1 project as well.

b) if native, create your own native Universal C# application. In your MFPF project, add Windows Phone 8  Universal native API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer vivin K, it really helps me a lot, Can you just elaborate for the option "a" i.e how to add a 'Windows 8 Universal' environment? I was currently re-targeting windows phone 8 version to windows phone 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: In MFP studio 7.1, you will notice a new environment - Windows 8 Universal. This environment is not available in MFP 7.0

Comment: Thanks   @VivinK for that clarification

Comment: @VivinK Just out of curiosity since you mentioned that WNS is only for Universal Windows Apps according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642085%28v=vs.105%29.aspx it says "Benefits of using WNS in your Silverlight 8.1 app" and it seems to support it according to Microsoft... but I've ran into many posts like this one that say its not supported. Anyways I'm just trying to find the correct answer since its confusing that Microsoft would post something that says the complete opposite... Thanks!

Comment: @Lord-Link, I should have said that the statement is specific to MobileFirst platform. I have corrected my answer to reflect this.